# Assignment operator not always called on templated class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I get strange things here. There is a class template:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class ValueType>
class OpTest {
    public:
        //normal ctor
        OpTest(ValueType newVal):myVal(newVal) {};

        //disable copy ctor
        template<class OtherValue>
        OpTest(const OpTest<OtherValue>& other) = delete;
        
        // getter operator
        operator ValueType () { 
            std::cout << "Getter called" << std::endl;
            return myVal;
         }

        // setter operator
        template<class OtherValue>
        void operator= (const OtherValue& val) { 
            std::cout << "Setter called" << std::endl;
            myVal = static_cast<ValueType>(val);
         }
    private:
        ValueType myVal;
};
```

and a class that has an `OpTest` type field:

```
class Tester {
    public:
        OpTest<int> value;

        Tester():value(5) {};
};
```

It works fine for a such code:

```
Tester object;
int v = object.value; // operator ValueType() called
object.value = 42; // operator= (ValueType&) called
```

but somehow this code:

```
Tester objA, objB;
objA.value = objB.value;
```

doesn't call any of my overloaded operators from `OpTest`.

The reason I'm doing my setter operator like that is because I want to my program do some conversion from `OtherValue` into `ValueType` inside that method. However the insides of the method isn't important as it is not called at all with the last code example. Why? Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? `objA.value = objB.value` translates to `objA.value.operator=(objB.value);` and that should be your setter operator.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your example does not compile and you have left out important details that are needed to answer your question.

Comment: objA.value = objB.value, maybe is a no-op because of value being uninitialized data?

Comment: @Felix.leg There is nothing strange. You forgot about the copy operator:
`OpTest& operator = (const OpTest& obj) { 
            std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
            myVal = obj.myVal;
            return *this;
         }`

Comment: @B0FEE664 it works, but your solution confuses me: why the more general "setter operator" wasn't chosen for the 'objA.value = objB.value'? Does it mean when writhing class templates I must consider a special case when my template operates on itself?

Comment: @Felix.leg [link](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.copy.assign)
>A user-declared copy assignment operator X​::​operator= is a non-static **non-template** member function of class X with exactly one parameter of type X, X&, const X&, volatile X&, or const volatile X&.